# REST API - Picklist UI API Error

Tags: community, profile, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies, ui-api

I have written apex code block to fetch picklist values for dependent picklist fields for a custom object using Picklist UI API for Community Portal users.

The request URL looks like this:
https:///services/data/v46.0/ui-api/object-info/Custom_Object__c/picklist-values/

Though it is **working fine for Community Profile A**, it is **not working for Community  Profile B.**

For user with profile A I get the response body with the picklist field vales as expected, but for the same user with Profile B I get the following response body:

```
[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]
```

I have tried doing the following to eliminate some possible reasons:

- Used same user: once with Profile A and once with Profile B to ensure the root cause is not something related to User differences
- There is no difference in Object level permissions between Profile A & B
- There is no difference in record type access between both profiles
- Ensured same request URL for the same object and for the same record type for which both profiles have access
- Ensured that the field level access for all picklist fields on this custom object is same for both profiles A & B

API related settings:

**Enable Record Visibility API** - **Disabled** for both profiles

**API Enabled** - **Enabled** for both profiles

**API Only User** - **Disabled** for both profiles

---

Please let me know if there are any other profile level settings/permissions that might cause this difference in response for Picklist UI API callout?

Comment: Have you checked in the debug logs the URL is being built the same way with both users? Likewise, shouldn't the url have /picklist-values/{recordtypeId}/{fieldApiName}?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KrisGoncalves, I have now updated my question (URL).

Yes, I am getting the same URL in debug log for both the profiles (used same user), and I am not using the fieldAPIname in the end as I am trying to get the  picklist values for all fields for the object

Comment: To my knowledge the UI API Request Url needs to use specific recordTypeId or Master Recordtypeid if no real Recordtypes are present. So for no RecordTypes, I use `/services/data/v47.0/ui-api/object-info/MyCstomObject__c/picklist-values/012000000000000AAA` as request url. cf. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values.htm
Not sure if this mitigates User A vs User B

Comment: I have used the master record type id and tried using another record type that both profiles have access to, but it still doesn't work.